# for loop delivering multiple times same entries out of an array / playground not, why?

Tags: swift, for-loop

I would like to ask, am I somehow wrong or is this the "normal" behavior.
While putting the following code into a class and calling it via click on button it delivers me multiple times the same output. But putting this into playground it delivers me only once the output.

It belongs to this code:

```
class fruits {

    var fruitID: String!
    var fruitName: [String]!
    var fruitColor: [String]!

    init(fruitID: String, fruitName: [String], fruitColor: [String]) {
        self.fruitID = fruitID
        self.fruitName = fruitName
        self.fruitColor = fruitColor
    }

}
```

--> CODE

```
var i_fruitID = "AAA"
var i_fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"]
var i_fruitColor = ["red", "yellow"]

var myFruit = fruits(fruitID: i_fruitID, fruitName: i_fruits, fruitColor: i_fruitColor)
var myFruits = [fruits]()

myFruits.append(myFruit)

for fruit in myFruits {

    println("++ FRUITID ++ : \(fruit.fruitID)")

    for fruitName in fruit.fruitName {
        println("++ FRUITNAME ++ : \(fruit.fruitName)")
        //break
    }

    for fruitColor in fruit.fruitColor {
        println("++ FRUITCOLOR ++ : \(fruit.fruitColor)")
        //break
    }   
}
```

<-- CODE

RESULT:

```
**in CODE:**

++ FRUITID ++  : AAA
++ FRUITNAME ++ : [Apple, Banana]
++ FRUITNAME ++ : [Apple, Banana]
++ FRUITCOLOR ++  : [red, yellow]
++ FRUITCOLOR ++  : [red, yellow]


**in PLAYGROUND:**

++ FRUITID ++  : AAA
++ FRUITNAME ++ : [Apple, Banana]
++ FRUITCOLOR ++  : [red, yellow]
```

While putting BREAK into the code it prints only once like in playground.
What is now the matter here?

Comment: Inside your second for loop, you're printing `fruit.fruitName` but `fruit` doesn't change in the inner for loop. Rewrite it to `fruitName`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Kametrixom, the solution looks like:

```
for fruit in myFruits {

    println("++ FRUITID ++ : \(fruit.fruitID)")

    for fruitName in fruit.fruitName {
        println("++ FRUITNAME ++ : \(fruitName)")
        //break
    }

    for fruitColor in fruit.fruitColor {
        println("++ FRUITCOLOR ++ : \(fruitColor)")
        //break
    }   
}
```